# How to allow some specfic character from long text in telerik column

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have an aplication in asp.net MVC and using telerik grid for displaying the record. Now one of my field has some large text about 1000 character due to which the text is getting extended vertically and layout is not looking good.
Is there any way to show some specific number of character in the column and show the whole text  in a tool tip on mouse hover or any other way to show the complete text for that column.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms Telerik controls I have implemented it like. Try it in your asp.net Telerik controls.

Use `Max Length` property to display specific number of text and then use it like.

```
private void yourGrid_ToolTipTextNeeded(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.ToolTipTextNeededEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataCellElement cell = sender as GridDataCellElement;
    if (cell != null)
    {
        GridViewRowInfo rowInfo = cell.RowInfo;
        string columnHeaderName = CommonMethods.GetStringValue(rowInfo.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].ColumnInfo.UniqueName.ToLower());
        if (columnHeaderName.ToLower().Equals("usagetype"))
        {
            e.ToolTipText = CommonMethods.GetStringValue(cell.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me check in which event you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET MVC, you have complete control over column rendering in the Grid when you use a TemplateColumn. In that case, you could do something like this to handle long values:

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns => 
        {
            columns.Template(c => {
            %>
                <span title="<%= c.FieldName %>"><%= c.FieldName.Elipsis(50) %></span>
            <%
            });
        })
        .Render();
 %>
```

Where "Elipsis(int)" is potentially an Extension Method that you create for String to truncate a string to a specific length and then add the "..." (note: this will obviously only work for server binding).

Another option is to use jQuery and an Elipsis plug-in to target your elements and truncate them. If you use the Template column to give your SPANs a specific class or ID, you can easily use jQuery selectors to apply the Elipsis effect. Here is an example plug-in:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/ellipsis-html-css/

You can go even further and use the Grid's `CellAction` event (again, for server binding) and apply your jQuery effect selectively. For more on `CellAction`, see this online demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/customformatting

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a CSS3 solution.

You just need to apply to the TD of the grid. The current version I am using has the class .t-grid with the Telerik grid.

A solution is to add in your stylesheet the CSS property `text-overflow` and you will be able to set it to **ellipsis**.

```
.t-grid td
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis 
}
```

It seems to work with the latest IE, FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I have added few more style parameters along with which is mentioned by @Patrick.
you can try this

```
.t-grid td
    {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0;
    border-left-width:1px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    white-space:nowrap;
    line-height:1.6em;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis
    }
```

I hope this will be helpful.